# How can I set a static login detail credentials in my code in angular?

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm new to angular and I wanted to set the username and password values to be static, so that only that username can be used to login to the app

I searched the web and got a few solutions but i'm confused with how i could implement with my app

`this is the login button in HTML`

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" color="primary" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="loginCheck()">Login</button>
```

`this is the loginCheck()function`

```
loginCheck(){

        if(this.form.valid){
            const userCategory = this.form.value.userCategory;
          const userName = this.form.value.userName;
          const passwd = this.form.value.passwd;

          console.log(userCategory, userName, passwd);

          this._storage.set('IS_LOGGED_IN', true);
          this._authService.isLoggedIn = true;

          this.router.navigate(['admin']);
        }
      }
```

i want to set a static login credentials in the code to allow user to login. As of now. any user can type in any login credentials and login.

Comment: Angular provides a special feature for login 'AuthGard'. and create services for this.

Comment: you can also follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3_6a7anWBQ

Comment: thanks for the link @Md.AbuSayed, but in the video he gives a way to navigate when the route is selected whereas in my case i want to give a static login credential set, so that the user can login only with one email id and password

Comment: you can check account type or credential, when credentialing  given access then you check username and password, 

That means you add a 3 condition for login

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not very good idea to make it static.

Second, if you anyway want to do so.

after get the value from form you can check like :

> userName === 'xyz' && passwd === 'abc

if above condition passes then only allow user to login.

Hope this answers your requirement.

Comment: I'm doing it for demo purpose so i think that's ok to be static for the moment. and may i know where should I add your line in my code?

Comment: if(userName === 'xyz' && passwd === 'abc'){ this.router.navigate(['admin']); }

Answer (score 0):

If you want your username and passward to be static make it hardcoded. In your loginCheck function of component file,

```
loginCheck(){

    if(this.form.valid){
        const userCategory = this.form.value.userCategory;
      const userName = 'admin'; //this.form.value.userName;
      const passwd = 'admin'; //this.form.value.passwd;

      console.log(userCategory, userName, passwd);

      this._storage.set('IS_LOGGED_IN', true);
      this._authService.isLoggedIn = true;

      this.router.navigate(['admin']);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing all the static fields in localstorage in `ngOnInit(){}` life-cycle hook of Angular.

```
ngOnInit(){
    localstorage.setItem("username","Admin");
    localstorage.getItem("username","Admin");
}


login(){
   let username = localstorage.getItem("username");
   let password = localstorage.getItem("password");
}
```

Later after loggingIn, you can delete these credentials. 
More Better static/Testing approach would be to implements route guard that let you log-in based on a fake-valid-JWT you store in your local storage.